# How to configure a redirect from www on a server Amazon?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, bitnami

We have placed a site (Wordpress) on the server through Amazon Bitnami.
We tried to set up a redirect from www.site.com to site.com (dropping the “www”).
However, it now redirects from any www sub-page to the home page www.site.com (and not to proper sub-page). (from www.site.com/page to site.com and not to site.com/page)
How to set up a redirect with www sub-page to the same page of the site without www.?

I added code to the Apache httpd.conf file.
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

`AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.`
     `It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:`
     `AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit`

```
`AllowOverride All`
```

Have also been edited files: .htaccess, httpd-app.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

Its probably just an htaccess issues. Try using this code in your htaccess, replace example with your sitename

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```